# Bootstrap rows in loop of WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I tried so hard, tried so many things but nothing works for me...

Can someone please help me out?

What I have: 3 columns on each row but it only creates 1 row in the loop...
What I want: 3 columns wrapped in a new row

Here is my code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row main-row">
    <div class="col-md-9 main-content">
        <div class="row post-row">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="post">
                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail( '', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive post-thumbnail' ) );
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="post-content">

                        <h3 class="post-title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
                        </h3>

                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="rating">
                                    <?php
                                    echo do_shortcode('[mr_rating_result show_count="false"]');
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="views">
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <?php echo_views(get_the_ID()); ?> <?php _e('views', 'huge-fights'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            $wplinkpages = array(
                'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'Pages:', 'huge-fights' ),
                'after'            => '</p>',
                'link_before'      => '',
                'link_after'       => '',
                'separator'        => ' ',
                'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page', 'huge-fights' ),
                'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page', 'huge-fights' ),
                'pagelink'         => '%',
                'echo'             => 1
            );

            wp_link_pages( $wplinkpages );

            ?>
                <?php
            $counter = 0;
            $counter++;

            if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
                  echo '</div><div class="row">';
                }
            ?>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            </div>

                <h1 class="content-title"><?php _e('Nothing found', 'huge-fights') ?></h1>
                <p><?php _e('Nothing found here, sorry!', 'huge-fights'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs sidebar">
        <?php get_sidebar('primary'); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I put $counter = 0; outside the while loop because when it is in the while loop it 'll just return '1'. Because it is in a loop.

So the good code 'll be:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

     $counter = 0;
<div class="row main-row">
    <div class="col-md-9 main-content">
        <div class="row post-row">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="post">
                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail( '', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive post-thumbnail' ) );
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="post-content">

                        <h3 class="post-title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
                        </h3>

                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="rating">
                                    <?php
                                    echo do_shortcode('[mr_rating_result show_count="false"]');
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="views">
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <?php echo_views(get_the_ID()); ?> <?php _e('views', 'huge-fights'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            $wplinkpages = array(
                'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'Pages:', 'huge-fights' ),
                'after'            => '</p>',
                'link_before'      => '',
                'link_after'       => '',
                'separator'        => ' ',
                'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page', 'huge-fights' ),
                'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page', 'huge-fights' ),
                'pagelink'         => '%',
                'echo'             => 1
            );

            wp_link_pages( $wplinkpages );

            ?>
                <?php

            $counter++;

            if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
                  echo '</div><div class="row">';
                }
            ?>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            </div>

                <h1 class="content-title"><?php _e('Nothing found', 'huge-fights') ?></h1>
                <p><?php _e('Nothing found here, sorry!', 'huge-fights'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs sidebar">
        <?php get_sidebar('primary'); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```